# Renaming column header in DataGridView Control using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I tried out the following code but the columns still inherit the table's field names

```
   DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("student_attendance_table")
    With DataGridView1
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).Name = "Register No."
        .Columns(1).Name = "Date"
        .Columns(2).Name = "Year"
        .Columns(3).Name = "Batch"
        .Columns(4).Name = "Hour 1"
        .Columns(5).Name = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(6).Name = "Hour 3"
        .Columns(7).Name = "Hour 4"
        .Columns(8).Name = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(9).Name = "Attendance"
    End With
```

Content follows:

```
1138M0345   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0346   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0347   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0348   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0349   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0350   27-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0343   27-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0344   27-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
```

Also I need to sort the content in ascending order using REGNO (The first column)

I am using vb.net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the column header use the `.HeaderCell.Value = "Display Value"`

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("student_attendance_table")
    With DataGridView1
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Register No."
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Date"
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Year"
        .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Batch"
        .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Hour 1"
        .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Hour 3"
        .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Hour 4"
        .Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Attendance"
    End With
```

and for initial sorting you can use

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me after you posted in 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

or `SELECT rollno as 'RollNo', name as 'Name', class as 'Class' FROM student_tbl`
this will rename the header

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively `"Data Grid Object".Columns("column index").HeaderText = "value"` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("student_attendance_table")
    With DataGridView1
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Register No."
        .Columns(1).HeaderText  = "Date"
        .Columns(2).HeaderText  = "Year"
        .Columns(3).HeaderText  = "Batch"
        .Columns(4).HeaderText  = "Hour 1"
        .Columns(5).HeaderText  = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(6).HeaderText  = "Hour 3"
        .Columns(7).HeaderText  = "Hour 4"
        .Columns(8).HeaderText  = "Hour 2"
        .Columns(9).HeaderText  = "Attendance"
    End With
```

Try this, I used same. Working for me!

Comment: Maybe add some explanation

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee, Is this explanation satisfied ?

Comment: @evry1falls - Unless I'm not seeing it, but this has no explanation.

Comment: The above answer and this answer are both suitable for **Renaming column header in DataGridView Control using vb.net**